How can i make the html textarea more robust and hadle mor text fomatting?
i need a text area where the user could write an article, add titles, subtitles and newlines
I dont want to use  TinyMCE or paid services and chagpt recomend to do a cript that adds  to the tags i dont think that is user friendly
